# node js mongoose express-fileupload replacing error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm creating an upload for a project. So i created two routes for my upload. 1st is when the user registration part will upload an image the 2nd one is if a driver adding a vehicle he can add a image of the vehicle.

The problem is when i run a function for the 1st time it works as i expected. but if i run the other router after running any of those function. the file replace as the last uploaded file name. so please help me to fix it

here is the user registration upload function

```
if(req.files.file.name.split('.').pop() == 'jpg' || 
    req.files.file.name.split('.').pop() == 'jpeg' || 
    req.files.file.name.split('.').pop() == 'png') {
    Uploads
    .findOne({}, {}, { sort: { 'created_at' : -1 }},
    function(err, last){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!last) {
            Uploads
            .create({
                filename: fileName + '.' + extension,
                path: licenseImg
            },
            function(err, license){
                if(err) throw err;
                Driver
                .create({
                    driver_id: user._id,
                    driving_license_copy: license._id
                },
                function(){
                    req.files.file.mv(licenseImg + req.files.file.name, function(err){
                        if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
                        fs.rename(licenseImg + req.files.file.name, licenseImg + fileName + '.' + req.files.file.name.split('.').pop(), function(err){
                            if(err) throw err;
                            config.sendWithHash(
                                user.email,
                                'Verify Your account',
                                'Please click the link down below to verofy your account \n http://localhost:1200/user/verify/email/',
                                user.NIC + user.phone + user.email
                            );
                            res.send({
                                message: 'New user created, Please verify your email first',
                            });
                        })
                    })
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            var filename = last.filename;
            var renamedName = filename.split('_')[0] + "_" + parseInt(parseInt(filename.split('.')[0].substr(filename.split('.')[0].lastIndexOf('_')+1))+1);
            console.log(filename);
            console.log(renamedName);
            Uploads
            .create({
                filename: renamedName + '.' + extension,
                path: licenseImg
            },
            function(err, license){
                if(err) throw err;
                Driver
                .create({
                    driver_id: user._id,
                    driving_license_copy: license._id
                },
                function(){
                    req.files.file.mv(licenseImg + req.files.file.name, function(err){
                        if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
                        fs.rename(licenseImg + req.files.file.name, licenseImg + renamedName + '.' + req.files.file.name.split('.').pop(), function(err){
                            if(err) throw err;
                            config.sendWithHash(
                                user.email,
                                'Verify Your account',
                                'Please click the link down below to verofy your account \n http://localhost:1200/user/verify/email/',
                                user.NIC + user.phone + user.email
                            );
                            res.send({
                                message: 'New user created, Please verify your email first',
                            });
                        })
                    })
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
else {
    res.send('Cannot upload that type of files');
}
```

this is the other upload function executes where the driver adding a vehicle

```
Uploads
.findOne()
.sort({ 'created_at' : -1})
.exec(function(err, last){
    if(err) throw err;
    var filename = last.filename;
    var filePath = './public/uploads/vehicles/';
    var extension = last.filename.split('.').pop();
    var renamedName = filename.split('_')[0] + "_" + parseInt(parseInt(filename.split('.')[0].substr(filename.split('.')[0].lastIndexOf('_')+1))+1);
    console.log(last);
    console.log(filename);
    console.log(renamedName);
    Uploads
    .create({
        filename: renamedName + '.' + extension,
        path: filePath
    },
    function(err, vehicleImg){
        if(err) throw err;
        Vehicle
        .create({
            driver_id: req.decoded._doc._id,
            make: req.body.make,
            model: req.body.model,
            year: req.body.year,
            registration_no: req.body.reg_no,
            vehicle_img: vehicleImg._id
        },
        function(){
            req.files.file.mv(filePath + req.files.file.name, function(err){
                if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
                fs.rename(filePath + req.files.file.name, filePath + vehicleImg.filename, function(err){
                    if(err) throw err;
                        res.send({
                            message: 'Vehicle added',
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

So here is all of the code that error coming from. if anybody knows why is that, please let me know how to fix it

thank you

Comment: `[  'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png' ].some(x => x === req.files.file.name.split('.').pop())` Little contribution to replace the `if(x || y || z)`

Comment: Aren't you using multer SDK from Express.js ?

Comment: no i'm not using multer coz i couldn't understand the process it.
so is there anyway to fix the issue i;m using express-fileupload to upload the file